# dbus Failed to connect to system bus: Error.LimitsExceeded: The maximum number of active connections for UID 1019 has been reached

Tags: gnome-shell, d-bus

(title was unable to create 50+ VNC+Gnome sessions (dubs/systemctl limits) )

I am trying to create 50 VNC display session on a CentOS 7.6 machine.  I created a local user.  Once logged in, I could create only 9 sessions.

After this VNC Server starts, immediately errors out with

```
Sample VNC log
Copyright (C) 1999-2017 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12001000, The X.Org Foundation


Mon Nov 25 12:42:38 2019
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5959
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
/localhome//iesdvnc/.vnc/xstartup: line 5: 28820 Trace/breakpoint trap   /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

dmesg has something like below...

```
   47.022483] traps: gnome-session-b[10647] trap int3 ip:7fd7ea82fb11 sp:7ffd0a245090 error:0
[   55.985977] traps: gnome-session-b[11755] trap int3 ip:7f81b8595b11 sp:7ffdbfee0910 error:0
[   60.403733] traps: gnome-session-b[12603] trap int3 ip:7fb06491ab11 sp:7ffd42f68e00 error:0
[   60.982362] traps: gnome-session-b[13356] trap int3 ip:7fa59f459b11 sp:7ffea65498d0 error:0
[   62.825407] traps: gnome-session-b[14135] trap int3 ip:7f2e4334fb11 sp:7ffd33387220 error:0
```

I suspect this is to do with system limits for user or dbus limits. I am unable to proceed though.  Please suggest what could be changed to create tens of VNC displays.

After more debugging error is 
(from # abrt-cli list )

```
ERROR: Failed to connect to system bus: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.LimitsExceeded: The maximum number of active connections for UID <user id> has been reached
```

Comment: It mentions a few configs you may be able to tweak here: https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8393